# Unable to get EAPOL packets in monitor mode

Tags: network, wireshark, monitoring

I am not able to get EAPOL packets on Wireshark. I've provided my AP's PSK decryption key to protocol 802.11 and adjusted my monitor mode interface's(TP-Link WN722N) frequency channel correctly. I got only 802.11 and LLC frames and not able to see any HTTP, TCP and EAPOL pdu although I have all traffic types multicast/unicast/broadcast, up to MCS7 for 802.11bgn.

Is my potential problem only decryption of frames or a frequency mismatch? Are there any required configuration to get EAPOL packets?

Comment: And you are definitely using EAPOL on your network, yes?

Comment: No, I don't know how to determine it.

Comment: So, do you use RADIUS to authenticate devices?

Comment: No, I don't use RADIUS authentication

Comment: have u detect and use the correct channel?  WIFI have many different channel, and you will need 14 different adaptor to collect all the different channel concurrently:   https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/62565/wifi-adapter-that-allows-monitoring-multiple-frequencies.   The proper sequence is authen + probe + association request and response packet, to be followed by the 4 way handshake, which is EAPOL setting up the encrypted channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by rebooting my AP during Wireshark capture session. After doing that Wireshark could capture EAPOL packets, then decryption worked as well. However, I cannot capture all packets in the WLAN traffic and don't know why.